# Strategy to detect VIM mode?

Tags: vim, keyboard, mode

I aim to write a deamon which will change the lighting of my keyboard if VIM is in Insert Mode, or if VIM is in command mode.

I am stuck on considering how I could extract the information about what mode VIM actually is in at any given time.  I have tried investigating all files in the /proc/ folder associated with a running VIM process, but have no found anything that could give insight as to what mode the editor currently is in.

I am aware that you can have VIM run a command with a setting in you ~/.vimrc as so:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * checktime
```

...but I am not sure how I could use this to programmatically (language is irrelevant right now) change state based on VIM mode.
Thank you.

Comment: Would calling a function (from an autocommand) that'll write to an indicator file/socket/whatever to be read by your daemon work for you?

Comment: Michail, thank you for the reply.  If I had VIM write a "1" or "0" to a random file in my filesytem, and then have my program read and check that file constantly, is this a proper way to go about status indications?  Where is the typical location that such a file should reside?  It is under my impression that process oriented files live in the /proc/ directory, which is why I checked there first for any preexisting mechanisms.  Where are some "correct" places I could put that file?  What exactly do you mean by writing to a socket?  As in a networking socket?

Comment: Sorry, can't really help you here. I have little to no expertise in interprocess communication, just some meager general knowledge. A socket doesn't need to be for networking, can be a local thing; writing to it is usually the same as writing to a regular file. Can't really say about "correct places", I've seen some under `/var`, but I _think_ `tmux` keeps its sockets under `/tmp`, so here's that.

Comment: Indeed, at that point, you might just write a script and have an autocommand `au CursorHold * exec printf("!myscript %s", mode())`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That would involve a 4-second delay, though (by default)...

Comment: @Amadan sure but you could add other events (InsertLeave, &c)

Comment: how do you plan to change the colour on the keyboard? Do you already have a script or something else? Should be trivial as long as there is only one vim instance. For more than one instance you may need a thread-safe counter somewhere.

Comment: @Doktor OSwaldo, I am using the ckb-next project on GitHub which runs a daemon to communicate with Corsair hardware.  I can change the color profile of my keyboard by sending a command to the daemon:
`echo mode <n> switch | sudo tee /dev/input/ckb1/cmd`

So I could have VIM use an autocommand to update its mode status to some pipe or file (this is what I am unclear about), and then have my own program echo commands to the ckb-next daemon depending on what I want.

Comment: well the easiest solution would be to just send your command from vi `autocmd InsertEnter system("echo mode <n> switch | sudo tee /dev/input/ckb1/cmd")` but as said before, if it has to work with multiple vim instance, you will need a counter